# Trajectory similarity: calculate distance between two trajectories

Tags: python, coordinate-system, trajectory

I have two sets of coordinates.
And I'd like to calculate the distance between two trajectories by Python.
Especially, I'd like to get the point which is the most distant.

How can I calculate ? Or are there any libraries or tools something like that to calculate easily ?